# Iphone Game development Esimate

Tags: iphone

I have been asked to give an estimate for an iphone game application.

I really have bad estimates for game application.

Can you share me links or stuff which will give me some idea of how long it will take me to develop the game.

I know this is very crude data, but some link that will give me database or share experiences about how much time other developers took for different games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends on your skills Amol.

Among other elements:

- will you be doing the art assets, or are they given to you
- are you designing the game, or just implementing it
- do you "discover" Objective-C or are you an experienced iPhone or even Mac business application developer?

All these change your estimate drastically.

You also have to take into account the technique you will use:

- pure OpenGL
- Cocos2D
- Unity

which partly depends on the previous questions.

Then you need to know which frameworks you intend to use:

- Quartz
- Core Graphics
- Core Data
- Game Center

and many other possibilities.

If the game is very simple, you probably won't need a database or a leaderboard. If you're implementing a huge tridimensional multiplayer online roleplaying game client, you might need a team to help you out.

You need to figure out the answers to all this before you can even put out a time estimate...